# MFCC - Why 13 Coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, signal-processing

Basically I am trying to computer a MFCC and wondered if you can help.

This is the FFT of 1 of the Frames (After I have multiplied the Hamming Window by the Mel Bank Filters) :

[image]

Here is the DCT of the FFT of Frame 1:

[image]

I have read somewhere that I need to take 13 Coefficients from each frame in which I can then carry out a DTW algorithm to identify the signal. BUT why 13 and how do you extract these? I've read a paper that gives an equation to calculate the energy, however, this wouldn't produce 13 Coefficients when the Frame is 256 in length. So do I take the first 13 values, then, compute the total energy on each of the values? Refer to "Step 7" in paper [enter link description here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.4083.pdf)

Hope someone can help, thanks :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask on the SE about DSP?